# typescript dynamic types and generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a hard time trying to wrap my head around typescript dynamic (and generic) types.

What I'm trying to accomplish is create a function that returns an object with a specific type where some properties of that object must match whatever parameters are given to that function.

So, basically what I want to happen (pseudo):

`const listRequest = createRequest('list', {ids: [1, 2]});`

this function should create me an object as follows:

```
{
  operationVersion: 1,
  protocolVersion: 2,
  operation: 'list', // first param
  list: {            // prop name must match with first param
    ids: [1, 2],     // second param
  }
}
```

For now, my code looks like:

```
interface IBaseRequest {
  operationId: number;
  protocolVersion: number;
  operation: string;
  authenticationToken?: string;
}

export type BaseRequest<Operation extends string> = {
  [Prop in keyof IBaseRequest]: IBaseRequest[Prop];
} & Record<Operation, any>;

type CreateRequestType = <T extends string>(operation: string, params: any) => BaseRequest<T>;

export const createRequest: CreateRequestType = <T extends string>(operation: string, params: any) => {

  const req = {
    operation: operation,
    operationId: 1,
    protocolVersion: 2,
  };

  req[operation] = params;
  return req as BaseRequest<T>;
};
```

Now, when create my request object with:

`const listRequest = createRequest('list', {a: 'aa'});`

I don't get the intellisense for `listRequest.list` nor that the type of listRequest being type of `BaseRequest<'list'>`

And if try to create the request with:

```
type ListRequest = 'list';
const test = <ListRequest>createRequest('list', {a: 'aa'});
```

I get an error:

```
Conversion of type 'BaseRequest<string>' to type '"list"' may be a mistake
because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was
intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with types and generics?

Comment: Is it possible that this doesn't work because it is intended to use `IBaseRequest` as class and not interface?

Comment: @sandrooco It really doesn't matter for me how this is done / implemented, as long as the end result is an object of type X<Y> with intellisense :) I'm pretty new to typescript types and generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a function is difficult to code in TypeScript. It's much simpler and terser with the following alternate version, taking a single "aggregated" input parameter, in your example it would be `{ list: { a: 'aa' }}`.

```
function createRequestBis<K extends string, T>(payload: { [k in K]: T }) {
    const operation = Object.keys(payload)[0] as K;
    return Object.assign({
        operationVersion: 1,
        protocolVersion: 2,
        operation,
    }, payload);
}

const listRequest = createRequestBis({ list: { a: 'aa' } });
listRequest; // Type { operationVersion: number... } & { list: { a: string } } -> True but ugly!
listRequest.operation; // Type "list" -> OK
listRequest.list.a;    // Type "string" -> OK
```

It works but the returned type that is inferred is a bit ugly. We can enhance it with a custom utility type that deconstruct+reconstruct an object type:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer Tb ? { [K in keyof Tb]: Tb[K] } : never;

const header = {
    operationVersion: 1,
    protocolVersion: 2
};

function createRequestPretty<K extends string, T>(payload: { [k in K]: T }) {
    const operation = Object.keys(payload)[0] as K;
    const result = Object.assign({ operation }, header, payload);
    return result as any as Prettify<typeof result>;
}

const listRequest2 = createRequestPretty({ list: { a: 'aa' } });
listRequest2; // Type { operation: "list"; operationVersion: number; protocolVersion: number; list: { a: string } } -> OK
```